# Restrict OS functionality for a user

Tags: windows, security, unix, restrictions

### Context

I'm volunteering on a project for my university that requires us to place a computer in the university atrium which should have access to only one predefined website. Website is a web service that would be of help to the students and would generate some pdf document that should then be printed by connected printer.

### Problem

I'm concerned about possible misuses of that computer. In ideal scenario it would only have access to that one website and it would print generated documents on the local printer that is connected to it, but in reality OS offers much, much broader possibilities and those should be restricted as much as possible.

So, I'm asking for help to find a way to restrict OS functionality to narrow it down to aforementioned use-case. I'm not sure what are the possibilities for **Windows or UNIX**, and would appreciate if you were to offer solutions for both.

To name a few things I would like to restrict for a user:

- Disable changing wallpaper
- Disable changing theme
- Disable changing screen saver
- ...
- Disable ability to install applications
- Disable log out or shutdown

Comment: What you are looking for is commonly referred to as "kiosk" or "kiosk mode". There are plenty of possibilities.

Comment: search for kiosk mode for Windows # as a start .

Comment: admin password for boot setup, disabled all boot sources except 1 drive.

Comment: I didn't even know how to google that. Seems like "kiosk mode" is what I'm  looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Linux distro [porteus kiosk](http://porteus-kiosk.org/).

It would seem cover every area of concern you have. It includes a website [whitelist](http://porteus-kiosk.org/parameters.html#whitelist) so you can lock things down to just one site.

There are other options but in terms of upfront cost (it's free) and setup time its by far the best option I've seen